# excel cubset function to get 2 columns set

Tags: excel, powerbi, mdx, powerpivot

I am trying to use the cubset function to get a set of 2 columns. The data table is something like bellow:

```html
TABLE
+--------+-------+-------+
| CLIENT | PRODA | PRODB |
+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 | A     | X     |
|      1 | A     | Y     |
|      1 | B     | X     |
|      2 | A     | Y     |
|      2 | B     | X     |
|      2 | C     | Y     |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

The code I running returns only 1 column set

`=CUBSET("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[TABLE].[CLIENT].&[1]*[TABLE].[PRODA].children";"result set")`

The code I am trying to perform,  I need to return both related columns PROD AND PRODB

`=CUBSET("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[TABLE].[CLIENT].&[1]*[TABLE].[PRODA].[PRODB].children";"result set")`

```html
result set
+-------+-------+
| PRODA | PRODB |
+-------+-------+
| A     | X     |
| A     | Y     |
| B     | X     |
+-------+-------+
```

So what is the correct way to write the code to retrieve both related columns ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: I'm not sure CUBESET can handle duplicates like you have. What do you intend to do with the result set?

Comment: Hi. I need to get data from the data model (in powerpivot ) but in my project using pivot table is not my intention so I am using Cube formulas instead. In this case Cubeset is working fine to get one column from the table but in my problem, column PRODB is dependent on PROA so I need to get both, as if using pivot tables, but instead using cube functions. Maybe Cubeset might not be the right function...

Comment: Yeah, I think this may not be the right approach. You likely want to do filtering instead.